# navigateByUrl intermittently failing

Tags: angular

I have a table listing and on each `<tr>` row I have a `(click)` event as follows:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let variant of variants" (click)="viewVariant(variant)" class="linked">
    <td>
        {{ variant.sku }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ variant.title }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

The method it calls is defined as:

```ts
viewVariant( variant: Variant ) : void {

    this.router.navigateByUrl('/variants/' + variant.id );
}
```

My problem is that sometimes it redirects correctly but more often than not it does not redirect, no reaction. If I angrily click multiple times it usually works (eventually). Can anybody please advise what would cause this issue?

Comment: Have you put in any kind of logging? Could you show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody suffering similar symptoms my issue was caused by over using the resolver classes. On one route I used 3 resolver components. I reduced to one resolver and everything worked hunky dory.

Be wary of resolvers and when to use them.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me...  Some questions: Why is resolvers an array if is supposed to use only one? How can one reuse the resolvers if we have to a unique resolver for each route/component? Also the link is now https://angular.io/guide/router#!#resolve-guard